# Android PreferenceFragmentCompat, preference title and summary not showing

Tags: android, fragment, android-preferences

I'm using `androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1`
Just want to integrate a simple Settings page in my existing app.

The preferences' `title` and `summary` won't show up.
I even changed the background from white to black.
Also even put a long text to see if the size changes (it did not change)
I've put the screenshots below

Also using `DrawerLayout` and Jetpack Navigation (`androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0`)

`SettingsFragment.kt`

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(26, 26, 26))
    }
}
```

`preferences.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Preference Category">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="checkbox"
            android:summary="Tap to check if on or off"
            android:title="Checkbox Preference" />
        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="switch"
            android:title="Switch Preference"
            android:summary="Click to switch on or off"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

`styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorGrayLight</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorYellowDarker</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's probably because you're setting the list view's colour in your `onViewCreated` lifecycle hook.

Comment: When I deleted the whole `onViewCreated` override, it displays only white, as seen on screenshot #2 and #3

Comment: Where is `listView` even defined in your SettingsFragment.kt?

Answer (score 0):

The Android Studio layout should show strings in the preview under Design tab. Could also be you overwrote something in the styles xml.

You could also create a new Android Studio project and only make the settings to check if something is wrong in your project.

My solution is a workaround, because I had styling issues with colors.

You create a custom layout for the preference views. I called this layout

preference_checkbox_custom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingStart="45dp"
android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:maxLines="10" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
<CheckBox
    android:id="@android:id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the preference xml you set the custom layout.

```
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="keySomething"
        android:title="Tap to check if on or off"
        android:layout="@layout/preference_checkbox_custom"/>
```

I set the text color to #FF0000. If it still doesn't work then its something else

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem
Solution is in the link

You should change:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

To:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Instead of posting part of the answer as a comment you should edit the answer and delete the comment

Comment: @SergeiKozelko and Anonymous
Thanks you both)
I'm trying)